# Никнейм работает не корректно

Tags: unity3d, codemirror

Я делаю игру в юнити на миррор, и сейчас я хочу сделать никнейм, однако мой скрипт работает не правильно. вот код

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using Mirror;
using TMPro;
using System;

public class Getname : NetworkBehaviour
{
    [SyncVar]
    public string nme;
    public TMP_Text nmee;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        if (isOwned)
        {
            if (isServer)
            {
                Cmdset();
            }
            else if(isClient)
            {
                Cmdset();
            }
        }
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }
    [Command]
    public void Cmdset()
    {
        nme = PlayerPrefs.GetString("nam");
        set();
    }

    [Server]
    public void set()
    {
        nmee.text = nme;
    }

    [Server]
    public void settt()
    {
        nme = PlayerPrefs.GetString("nam");
        nmee.text = nme;
    }
}
```

то есть у сервера не отображается никнейм, у 1 игрока ника тоже нету но сервер видит свой ник, а 2 игрока ника тоже нету но сервер видит свой ник, я возможно не правильно объяснил, если надо могу отправить видно как оно выглядит.